# How do I get a byte[] of the camera frame in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, simulation, frame, virtual

I am relatively new to Unity. I was wondering how I could get the byte[] frame of the virtual main camera in Unity.

I couldn't find any tutorials online?

Comment: This likely isn’t possible in most cases. The problem is that the GPU renders the scene, and then itself outputs to the screen in many cases. There are ways to capture it but it can be slow. There is probably a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: What is the reason for the capture? If it's for a screenshot, you can simply use https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RenderTexture for this:

- Create render texture
- Set it as [target texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html)
- [Render the current camera view](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.Render.html) to this texture
- Set the camera's render texture to null if it is not needed
- Create Texture2d
- Read data to the created Texture2d ([example can be found here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-active.html))
- [Get bytes from your Texture2d](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html)